# I can't move widgets in the Wordpress sidebar

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, widget

I have an issue with a wordpress theme that I'm using, where I cannot add widgets to the sidebars. The drag and drop function does not work.

I am able to move widgets around in other themes.

I was wondering what kind of code in the theme may be causing such an issue?

I have tried to fix this by adding a Google plugin, but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Are there any plusgin that allow me to edit widget without the drag and drop functionality needed by default?

Comment: Check in your console must be some js issue.

Comment: the only error that I have is: load-scripts.php:2TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'e.length')

This is in: Widgets>Scripts>LoadScripts.php

So it seems to be responsible... how would I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with themes that don't correctly enqueue jQuery. Switch to the twentytwelve theme and see if widgets work; if so, it's your theme. (It could also be a plugin problem.)

You need to 
use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what javascript is loading on your site and any errors.

Ask the theme developer if you can't debug javascript. The error you see `undefined' is not an object` is too vague to figure out without much more info.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - found out that by deactivating the feedburner plugin it got resolved. Some kind of possible conflict there - see if disabling any plugins would help?