# Wordpress Widgets not draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have an error in my Wordpress site, which is causing me to not be able to add / edit / remove / drag widgets in the admin area.

I have tried disabling each plugin one at at time to try to find the plugin causing the error, however have not found a solution

Please could someone provide advice which could help with fixing this problem?

Thank you

[Site](http://www.airport-game-lodge.co.za/)

Comment: This could be a theme problem, have you tried it in a standard WP theme like TwentyFourteen.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958210/i-cant-move-widgets-in-the-wordpress-sidebar?rq=1

Comment: Thank you @PeterWooster      One problem I have found is the following:  Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.